# Is this effect built in inside Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, canon-600d, color-correction

I watched this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yiWPkMRlaI

and loved the colors too much. I want to know how can I achieve colors like that in photo or video? Does 600D have that built it or is it a part of Photoshop / Lightroom?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are linking to a video, this is probably off topic.

Comment: The question does ask whether the effect is available for stills too.

Comment: One comment from uploader is `Yes. I adjusted curves with this footage in Premiere.`

Comment: Another comments: `I used the curve effect to play with color here.`, `Then I added sharpening and boosted the colours in post.`, `Edited in Premiere and color graded in After Effects`, `Tweaked the curves in After Effects to give it a cross processed look`, `Here I believe I simply edited the curves to try and achieve a kind of cross-processed look.
You can learn the principles for getting the cross processed look in Photoshop here (wwwdot)photographymad(dotcom)­/pages/view/digital-cross-proc­essing-in-photoshop and then use in AE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like those colours have been achieved using a kind of *cross-processing*. However if you look at the video description you'll see that the video has been processed with Adobe Premiere and Adobe After Effects CS5. The Canon 600D doesn't have that kind of processing built in.